# DataPicker's localization in WebSharper.JQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, f#, jquery-ui-datepicker, websharper

It is known that Datepicker of jQuery UI provides support for localizing its content to cater for different languages and date formats:

```
$( selector ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

Dear authors of WebSharper.JQueryUI, please tell me a way to do this in F#.

PS. I apologize if my question will seem trivial, since I'm only doing the first steps in WebSharper

Comment: You need to call JS methods to configure jQuery UI elements, it cannot be done without at least some JS. Your F# could generate the JS code, but unless you need to change things when rendering the page that is just making things harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just relied on the fact that this option is implemented in library, but is not documented